# Control underlying elements after popping up a dialog

Tags: android

I am popping up a dialog from an Application context by calling an intent which has a transparent theme.([Similar](http://www.sherif.mobi/2011/08/creating-global-dialogs.html) to what is mentioned here.)
The pop is a read only.The issue is that when the pop up is shown there is a current activity going on in the background. I need to be able to access the background activity too while the popup is dispalyed. I have added the following two lines but it still is not possible for me to control the underlying activity:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you must open the dialog in a thread, you haven't explained much about what you want to do in background ,but for making a thread do this:
create a new class with name:thread1 then write down these  there:

```
public class thread1 extends Thread {
MainActivity activity;
public  thread1(MainActivity m){
activity=m;
ProgressDialog pd;
//other code maybe for specification
pd=ProgressDialog.show(activity,"", "wait for background activity");
}
@Override
public void run(){
         //you code working in background here like:
         activity.sucess=0;
         while (activity.sucess==0){
        android.os.SystemClock.sleep(300);  
    }
    pd.dismiss();
}
}
```

whenever you want to open this pb you should write this,

```
thread1 t1=new thread1(this);
t1.start();
```

and when ever your work is done and you want to close the pb, you must set sucess=1 then the thread will be killed.